# Match HTTP_HOST within a RewriteRule instead of using RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of 301 redirects I need to make which contain varying domains all from within the same `.htaccess` file. I could write a RewriteCond for each rule as below and it works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule old-url-1a.htm /new-url-1a [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule old-url-1b.htm /new-url-1b [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule old-url-2a.htm /new-url-2a [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain2.com [NC]
RewriteRule old-url-2b.htm /new-url-2b [L,R=301]
```

But using this method I need to have 2 lines of code for every single URL which gets very lengthy and repetitive (the same RewriteCond is repeated many times).
Is there any way I can match the HTTP_HOST from within the RewriteRule directive itself? Something along these lines (conceptually):

```
RewriteRule www.domain1.com/old-url-1a.htm /new-url-1a [L,R=301]
RewriteRule www.domain1.com/old-url-1b.htm /new-url-1b [L,R=301]

RewriteRule www.domain2.com/old-url-2a.htm /new-url-2a [L,R=301]
RewriteRule www.domain2.com/old-url-2b.htm /new-url-2b [L,R=301]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Documentation says about RewriteRule:

> What is matched?
>
> The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string. **If you wish to match against the hostname**, port, or query string, **use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}**, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

But if you are able to put the rules inside your apache-config, there is another shorthand way: You could use a RewriteMap.

```
RewriteMap     host-redirects   txt:/etc/apache2/host-redirects.map
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*).htm$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/${host-redirects:%{HTTP_HOST}/$1|$1} [R,L]
```

The host-redirects.map would look like this:

```
www.domain1.com/old-url-1a.htm /new-url-1a/
www.domain1.com/old-url-1b.htm /new-url-1b/
www.domain2.com/old-url-2a.htm /new-url-2a/
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this! Unfortunately my sysadmin won't let me change the Apache config, so I guess I will have to resort to one massive pile of rules in my htaccess...

Answer (score 1):

BTW mapping may be the only way to debug "what is really matched"

You can set RewriteLogLevel to 9, the logs don't show what is parsed with `RewriteCond`.
Instead it says whether "it matched" or not. **Not very useful**.

Using maps (`RewriteMap`), the logs clearly say what key is passed.
Example :
`(/var/log/http/rewrite.log)
map lookup OK: map=host-redirects[txt] key=WHAT_IS_PARSED -> WHAT_IS_RETURNED`
or
`map lookup FAILED: map=host-redirects[txt] key=WHAT_IS_PARSED`

Using RewriteRule, the right term after | designates  the default returned value.
In most cases, a default 404.html page or somewhat. **Very useful**.

So in your httpd.conf, set
`RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log
RewriteLofLevel 9`
in your virtualhost, and you're done :)